# JupyterLab can not open on anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

when I click it
[image]
but it is not respond [image]
My browser don't be open
when I quit it

[image]

WTF???
I am crazy !!

thanks so much!!!!!

I just want to open JupyterLab ,why is so difficult....